# Add an attribute to an input element from a twig file

Tags: symfony

I have a form which is generated from inside a controller.
Then in twig file I need to add an attribute (placeholder) to a field (textarea).
What is the best way to do it in twig file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ form_row(form.yourField, { 'attr':{'placeholder':'sample value'} }) }}
```